# How can I see if a function pointer passed to a function returns void?

Tags: c

I have a function taking a function pointer, and I want to store the return value if the function pointed to by the pointer returns, and just run the function otherwise. Something like this:

```
static void threadStart(void (*function)(void*), void* arg) {                            
      if(function does not return void)  (void*) store = function(arg);  
       else(function())
};
```

How can I do this? I tried just doing:

```
static void threadStart(void (*function)(void*), void* arg) {                            
   (void*) store = function(arg);  
};
```

But this  produces a compilation error.

Comment: Since you declare `function` as `void (*function)(void*)`, it can't ever **not** return void, so it doesn't make sense to test whether it does.

Comment: *"this produces a compilation error."* - ***Always*** describe the compilation error.   The error messages have very helpful information in them!

Comment: Normally you won't have a situation where you need to pass multiple function pointers of different types to a function. This smells like a big picture program design issue and there's probably much better ways to achieve what you need. Such as establishing a standard function pointer format like `result func(some_struct* param);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have said, it's not possible.

Looking at what's being attempted, you should alter `function`'s signature so it returns a datatype with a sentinel value. For example, `function` could return a `void*` and you could check that it is not `NULL`.

So the parameters to `threadStart` would become `(void* (*function)(void*), void *arg)`. This matches a common design pattern used in libraries like `pthread_create`, which in its case has parameters `(void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Because `function` is declared as `void (*function)(void*)` it always returns void, so you don't need to.